# Pyautogui stops working after using "os.startfile"

Tags: python, operating-system, pyautogui

I'm creating a bot for installing a bunch of programs automatically but when I run it the pyautogui seems to not working.

Here I leave the code:

```
import pyautogui
import os
import time

def arturia3filters():
    os.startfile("MYDIRECTORY/Setup.exe")
    print('Opening Arturia 3 Filters')
    time.sleep(15)
    print('Trying to click icon')
    pyautogui.moveTo(1000, 560)
    pyautogui.click(x=1000, y=560)
    print('Clicked')
    time.sleep(4)
    pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'n')
    print('HT N')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'r')
    print('HT R')
arturia3filters()
```

Also when I try to run the program without the "os.startfile", it works good, very strange.

Comment: this suggests that the file might be incorrect. possibly use the full path for the file so that it is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

This works with the `full path` of the file. I create a test txt file in my c drive (on windows10) as per below and this is fine.

see code below.

```
import pyautogui
import os
import time

def arturia3filters():
    os.startfile(r"C:\darren\test.txt")
    print('Opening Arturia 3 Filters')
    time.sleep(15)
    print('Trying to click icon')
    pyautogui.moveTo(1000, 560)
    pyautogui.click(x=1000, y=560)
    print('Clicked')
    time.sleep(4)
    pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'n')
    print('HT N')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'r')
    print('HT R')
arturia3filters()
```

In my case, it opens the notepad text editor with the file that is pointed to in the `os.startfile()` command.